# How to loop through POST variables sent to ASP.NET WebMethod from JQuery $.ajax method?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, post, webmethod

I have a checklist created with HTML buttons that toggle between 'selected' and 'unselected' classes on click. Each option has an ID related with it and also an optional comment input.

I am trying to use the JQuery $.ajax() method with POST to send the IDs of the selected buttons and the related comment. The idea I have is to create a key/value collection of the IDs selected and their respective Comments when 'Save' is clicked like so:

```
selections = "{id1: 'comment1', id2: 'comment2', ...}"
```

Then pass it to the data portion of the $.ajax() method like so:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "MyPage.aspx/MyMethod"
     data: selections,
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     dataType: "json",
     success: function(msg) {
       onSuccess(msg);
     }
});
```

And finally access the selections in `MyMethod` by looping through `HttpContext.Current.Request.Form`.

But when I try this, `HttpContext.Current.Request.Form` is always empty. Is my approach wrong? If so, why? Can anyone suggest another approach?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Also, I know of 4 ways to call a server method from the JQuery AJAX API:

1. Page Method (static method in a .aspx page with the `[WebMethod]` modifier)
2. Switch statement between methods in `Page_Load` of a .aspx page
3. Switch statement between methods in `ProcessRequest` of a .ashx page
4. Web Service

Which way is most efficient? I assume 2 would involve an unnecessary instance of a Page, so that shouldn't be the one.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure your selections variable is valid JSON, what you wrote in your question is not valid JSON notation.

Second, in your webmethod definition, have the MyMethod receive a string as parameter; lets say you declare it as

```
[WebMethod]
public MyMethod(string selections)
{
    //Do processing here
}
```

In the body of your method., deserialize the string in a `Dictionary<string,string>` using the JavascriptSerializer, for example:

```
JavascriptSerializer js = new JavascriptSerializer(); 
Dictionary<string,string> result = js.Deserialize<Dictionary<string,string>>(selections);
```

Now you can loop through the elements in your dictionary.

Just to clarify, your selections variable needs to have every property enclosed in quotes; in your case, id1, id2... need to be 'id1':'comment','id2':'comment', etc.

**EDIT**

Adding code to demonstrate how the web service should be called.

```
var selections = "{'id1': 'comment1', 'id2': 'comment2'}";

$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "MyPage.aspx/MyMethod"
     data: JSON.stringify(selections),
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     dataType: "json",
     success: function(msg) {
       onSuccess(msg);
     }
});
```

As a last advice, get familiar with jsFiddle, it allows you to test things quickly. [See this](http://jsfiddle.net/A4quM/), for example.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've been following your directions and trying to get it working. For one, I guess you actually expect me to pass `{selections:'{id1:'comment1'}'}` instead of just `{id1: 'comment1'}` right? Only then can I retrieve `selections` in `MyMethod`. I got into `MyMethod` doing it this way with the parameter `selections` having the string value `"[Object object]"`. I have trouble deserializing this. I will come back after Labor Day weekend and work on this again and let you know how it goes. Thanks again!

Comment: @user924092 See my edit. I wrote what you need to do from the client-side. You were very close.

Comment: If we do pass the data as per your edit, the parameters in `MyMethod` would have to be `(string id1, string id2)` and NOT `(string selections)`. This doesn't solve my problem as the number of ids is unpredictable.

Comment: @user924092 well, JSON.stringify returns a string; therefore MyMethod can be declared as MyMethod(string selections){...} and the data parameter in the Ajax call can be: data: "'{'selections':'"+JSON.stringify(selections)+"'}'"; you can Deserialize this string in a Dictionary<string,string> as I explained above inside the body of MyMethod.

Comment: Got it working! I will post what I have in an answer.
+1 for pointing me to `JavaScriptSerializer`.
By the way, do you know if achieving the same through an ASHX handler and accessing the parameters through `context.Request.Form` inside `ProcessRequest` would be more efficient?

Comment: @user924092 I don't think an ASHX handler will be more efficient than a WebService. Web services are already very lean. Glad you got it working :)

Answer (score 0):

The selections variable should be an object not a string.

```
var selections = { id1: 'a', id2: 'b' };
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But since Page Methods expect a string containing JSON to be posted, I enclose the JSON object in a string.